# css3 add 3 images with percentages in one line that scale to the full extend of the browser

Tags: css

I have a background image that i want to use as my main navigation menu. What i want to do is to cut this image into slices and add rollover, hover events in certain areas/buttons. I was trying to have the same effect as the background-size cover but with a sliced image.

```
html { 
            background: url(../images/confetti.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

//EDIT
This is what i have done so far... http://translationgames.org/template.html this page has a css class for each image that defines the width in percentage. but it looks a bit stupid and it has rounding problems. note that as you rollover over certain areas things will appear this is why i want to have it as slices. I haven't create :hover stuff yet.

So i have an image that is cut to slices of different sizes one line is 1920 x 100 next line is three images of  220x320 800x320 900x320 third line is 1920x 233 etc. I am designing this for responsive design to cover all formats from 480px to 2560px+++  The way i though it will work is to have one background container div "bgcontainer" that has width 100% and then a background line div 
"backgline" which is inline-block and width 100%. Here is an example of the html

```
<div class="bgcontainer">
  <div id="backgline"> 
  <img src="images/images/backgroundfragments_01.jpg" alt="Translation games"><!--
  --></div>
  <div id="backgline"><!--
  --><img src="images/images/backgroundfragments_02.jpg" alt="Translation games"><!--
  --><img src="images/images/backgroundfragments_03.jpg" alt="Translation games"><!--
  --><img src="images/images/backgroundfragments_04.jpg" alt="Translation games"><!--
  --></div>
    <div id="backgline"> 
  <img src="images/images/backgroundfragments_05.jpg" alt="Translation games"><!--
  --></div>
```

and here is what i thought it will work with the css

```
#bgcontainer{width:100%;
}
#backgline {

    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    display: inline-block;
    position: inherit;
    font-size: 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;

    width : 100%;
    height:auto;


    /*min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 1280px; */


}
```

But this doesn't work the images break to lines. The full line image 1920px doesn't scale more than 100% as you can do with the background-cover and the three images in one line break to two lines and they don't scale more than their pixel width. I am obviously going to the wrong direction. Do you know how should i proceed ? Or something i should read? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you do a http://jsfiddle.net and clarify what you want to archive?

Comment: Sorry but i don't have the images online yet. I found that if i put a percentage in each sliced image the whole image scales properly. There is a problem with sub pixel rounding but i can re-cut it with more normal dimensions.

Comment: I just uploaded the page here http://translationgames.org/template.html

Comment: I have the impression that i have to do this page with javascript and not css3. The problem is that when the width goes under 800px the empty bottom start to appear. And i still struggle to create a :hover with the method i am using.